# Non-isomorphic graphs with same Tutte polynomial

Tags: polynomials, graph-theory, graph-isomorphism

I've been looking for some non-isomorphic graphs with the same Tutte polynomial. I'm aware of this [thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2380857/non-isomorphic-matroids-with-the-same-tutte-polynomial) and this [thread](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/275301/non-isomorphic-matroids-with-the-same-tutte-polynomial), however my understanding of matroids is non-existent, and they are a bit beyond the scope of the courses I'm taking.

If anybody could give me an example of a pair of non-isomorphic graphs with the same Tutte polynomial, I would be forever grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned on Wikipedia, the Tutte polynomial of any tree with $m$ edges is $x^m$. So take any two non-isomorphic trees of the same size, and you'll have the example you want.

As a random other example, the dart graph and the kite graph (shown below) both have Tutte polynomial $x^2 + 2 x^3 + x^4 + x y + 2 x^2 y + x y^2$:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! While waiting for an answer I stumbled upon the non-isomorphic trees as well, so I appreciate your other example a lot!

Comment: If you have access to Mathematica, then the database used by the `GraphData[]` command has precomputed Tutte polynomials for all the graphs it contains, so that makes it easy to find more examples.

Answer (score 1):

Call two graphs Tutte-equivalent if their Tutte polynomials coincide. Here is some [Macaulay2](http://www2.macaulay2.com/Macaulay2/) (M2) code for partitioning connected graphs on $n$ vertices via Tutte-equivalence. Once you have M2 installed and running just copy and paste the code below (changing $n=7$ to your favorite value of $n$).

```
{"Nauty", "Visualize", "Matroids"} / needsPackage -- load the necessary packages; ignore warnings
openPort "8080" -- needed for Macaulay2 to communicate with the default web browser
n = 7; -- number of vertices
S = ZZ[vars (0..n-1)]; -- a polynomial ring

-- use nauty to get all nonisomorphic connected graphs on n vertices
graphsOnN = generateGraphs (n, OnlyConnected => true); 

-- need to convert the graphs into a format the Matroids package understands
Gn = graphsOnN / (G -> stringToGraph (G,S)) / (G -> graph G#"edges"); -- the conversion

-- construct a common ring for all Tutte polynomials and a function mapping into that ring
tutteRing = ring tuttePolynomial matroid first random Gn;
comparableTutte = T -> sub (T, tutteRing);

-- now we partition all connected graphs via their Tutte polynomials
tuttePartition = partition (g -> comparableTutte tuttePolynomial matroid g, Gn);
tutteEquivalentHash = select (tuttePartition, v -> #v > 1 );
tutteEquivalentList = values tutteEquivalentHash;
```

Let's look at the data quickly. First we can check that out of the $853$ connected non-isomorphic graphs on $7$ vertices, $428$ are Tutte-unique, i.e., share their Tutte polynomial with no other graph (well, technically, no other connected graph on seven vertices).

```
# select (values tuttePartition, v -> #v === 1)
```

More generally we can see how many blocks of the partition of each size we have by entering

```
apply (values tuttePartition, v -> #v) // tally
```

which yields the output

```
Tally{1 => 428}
      2 => 42
      3 => 22
      4 => 12
      5 => 9
      6 => 3
      7 => 6
      9 => 1
      10 => 2
      11 => 3
      12 => 2
      18 => 2
```

We can use the command `visualize` to examine graphs in each block. For example, the graphs in one of the largest blocks are intimately related to dart and kite examples given by @Misha. If we enter the following

```
L = select (tutteEquivalentList, v -> #v == 18);
visualize L#0#0
```

then a browser window opens showing the following "three-headed dart"

[image]

whose Tutte polynomial, not surprisingly, is $x^3(x^3+2x^2+2xy+y^2+x+y)$.

For a more interesting example, the two graphs of the first block of size two are:

[image]
[image]

They share the Tutte polynomial $$x^{6}+5 x^{5}+5 x^{4} y+5 x^{3} y^{2}+5 x^{2} y^{3}+3 x y^{4}+y^{5}+10 x^{4}+15 x^{3} y+14 x^{2} y^{2}+9 x y^{3}+3 y^{4}+10 x^{3}+16 x^{2} y+12 x
  y^{2}+4 y^{3}+5 x^{2}+7 x y+3 y^{2}+x+y.$$